# Gitlab CE API; POST new Issue

Tags: api, gitlab

having a Problem posting a new issue via Ajax. The assigned User gets not set.

```
 $.ajax({
        url: "https://git/api/v3/projects/18/issues",
        async: true,
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        data: {
            private_token: "XXXXXXXX",
            title: "test",
            assignee_id: 2,
            description: "test"

        },
```

Request Body:

```
private_token=XXXX&title=test&assignee_id=2&description=test
```

Response Body:

```
{"id":16,"iid":12,"project_id":18,"title":"test","description":"test","state":"opened","created_at":"2015-08-24T13:33:35.042Z","updated_at":"2015-08-24T13:33:35.042Z","labels":[],"milestone":null,"assignee":null,"author":{"name":"api_user","username":"api_user","id":5,"state":"active","avatar_url":null,"web_url":"https://git/u/api_user"}}
```

[image]

I am not able to change the value of assignee:

what is wrong here?

Thanks for help!

Comment: I have updated your question please remove comments as not required now! you will get answer by some GIT fan :)

Answer (score 1):

Found the Problem:

guest users are not allowed to assign userids... so put the post user into Reporter Group and the Problem is gone!

Comment: Thanks, yeah, that's a shame gitlab just trash the input data, there should be an error...